# How to clean a dataframe where all the columns become one and we can't access individual column and it's values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
df = pd.read_csv("p4ds_esi_messy_data.txt", sep = "\t")
```

The messy dataset:

[image]

1. All the columns become one column while i tried. df.columns = [name mass radius density gravity....]
2. I want to unpack all the columns and access each column individually.

Comment: Please, add a header and a sample row from the txt file.

Comment: can you show sample data and how the columns are separated in the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you add a sample of the data so we can reproduce the issue. Having said that, by looking at the picture I think this will work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("p4ds_esi_messy_data.txt",  sep = '[*]')
```

Seems like the delimiter in your file is '*'.

Additional parameters might be needed but, again, we need a sample of the data to be able to help you out.

Comment: This is a data containing values mix off  '**'  and white spaces ........ while i ws trying to read the data by passing vrious delimeter also its showing only one column as all the columns and all the values mixed up and become a dataframe of only one column.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data?